# How do I find an object in an array of objects where each object can again have an array of the same object type

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to find an object in an array of objects, but the object I need to find can be in an other array of one of the objects.

I tried many variants of forEach loops with recursion methods

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "messages": [{
            "id": 4,
            "message": "XXXXXXXX",
            "code": "XXXXXX",
            "subMessages": null
        }, {
            "id": 8,
            "message": "XXXXXXXX",
            "code": "XXXXXX",
            "subMessages": [{
                    "id": 9,
                    "message": "XXXXXXXX",
                    "code": "XXXXXX",
                    "subMessages": null
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "id": 10,
            "message": "XXXXXXXX",
            "code": "XXXXXX",
            "subMessages": [{
                    "id": 11,
                    "message": "XXXXXXXX",
                    "code": "XXXXXX",
                    "subMessages": [{
                            "id": 12,
                            "message": "XXXXXXXX",
                            "code": "XXXXXX",
                            "subMessages": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The nesting count is not known and kan be more than shown in the example, and the arrays can contain more than 1 message each. What I am trying is to find a message by it's Id (Id's are unique over all messages).

Any tips?

Comment: This may help - http://jsfiddle.net/bradleytrager/ddPRp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
From what you mentioned, it looks like you just need to get the message against an id. 

If you need the entire message object, replace the line of code `returnData = messageObj.message;` with `returnData = messageObj;`

I have used array.some to achieve this instead of creating a for loop
```

```js
var messagesData = {
  "id": 1,
  "messages": [{
    "id": 4,
    "message": "4XXXXXXXX",
    "code": "XXXXXX",
    "subMessages": null
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "message": "8XXXXXXXX",
    "code": "XXXXXX",
    "subMessages": [{
      "id": 9,
      "message": "9XXXXXXXX",
      "code": "XXXXXX",
      "subMessages": null
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "message": "10XXXXXXXX",
    "code": "XXXXXX",
    "subMessages": [{
      "id": 11,
      "message": "11XXXXXXXX",
      "code": "XXXXXX",
      "subMessages": [{
        "id": 12,
        "message": "12XXXXXXXX",
        "code": "XXXXXX",
        "subMessages": null
      }]
    }]
  }]
};


function getMessageById(id) {
  var returnData;

  function searchForMessage(messages) {
    messages.some(function(messageObj) {
      if (messageObj.id === id) {
        returnData = messageObj.message;
        return true;
      } else if (messageObj.subMessages && messageObj.subMessages.length) {
        return searchForMessage(messageObj.subMessages);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
  searchForMessage(messagesData.messages);
  return returnData;
}

console.log(getMessageById(11));
console.log(getMessageById(4));
console.log(getMessageById(12));
```

```
Here is my jsfiddle link with the same code - https://jsfiddle.net/karthikeyan_shanmugavadivelan/3o0udv7f/11/
```